# Getting UUID of a VMware Virtual Machine using Ansible

Tags: ansible, vmware

We are working on Ansible Environemt. We wanted to connect to a Newly Deployed VM using its UUUID.

How to Get the UUID of a VMware Virtual Machine using Ansible so that i can establish the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the vmware_guest_facts module first, and retrieve the UUID. However, there are two identified as uuid, so I listed them both. I am assuming that the uuid you want is the instance_uuid.

```
tasks:
- name: get list of facts
  vmware_guest_facts:
    hostname: '{{ vc_name }}'
    username: '{{ vc_user }}'
    password: '{{ vc_pwd }}'
    datacenter: "{{ dc_name }}"
    name: "{{ vm_name }}"
    folder: "{{ dc_folder }}"
    validate_certs: False
  register: vm_facts

- set_fact:
    vm_uuid: "{{ vm_facts.instance.instance_uuid }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "product uuid hw : {{ vm_facts.instance.hw_product_uuid }}\n instance: {{ vm_facts.instance.instance_uuid }}"
```

Now continue on in your script and use {{ vm_uuid }} where you need the uuid to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible module `vmware_guest_facts` has been deprecated. This will not run in Ansible 2.9. You need to use the `vmware_guest_info` module instead.

---

```
- name: Getting VMWARE UUID
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: Get Virtual Machine info
    vmware_guest_info:
      validate_certs: no
      hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
      username: "{{ Password }}"
      password:  "{{ pass }}"
      validate_certs: no
      datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
      name: "{{ VM_Name }}"
      schema: "vsphere"
      properties:
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: vminfo
   - debug:
       var: vminfo.instance.config.uuid
```

The above code assumes you know the datacenter the VM is sitting on. If unsure of such you can also run the [following code](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vmware_vm_info_module.html#vmware-vm-info-module):

```
- name: Get UUID from given VM Name
  block:
    - name: Get virtual machine info
      vmware_vm_info:
        hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
        username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
        password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
        folder: "/datacenter/vm/folder"
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: vm_info

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.uuid }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ vm_info.virtual_machines | json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?guest_name=='DC0_H0_VM0']"
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you check this link: [The UUID Location and Format](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_move_uuid_format.html)

> It can be accessed by standard SMBIOS scanning software — for example
>   [**SiSoftware Sandra**](https://www.sisoftware.co.uk/download-lite/) or the [**IBM utility smbios2**](https://www.ibm.com/support/home/docdisplay?lndocid=TOOL-ASU) [...]